# Encrypt Data on mySql server without using php function

Tags: php, mysql, security, encryption

I have system which will interact with customers and customers will insert their personal and confidential data.

We are using Laravel 5. Can we encrypt data in mysql server without using any PHP functions?. Same way we should be able to retrieve data after decrypting.
I went though this link http://thinkdiff.net/mysql/encrypt-mysql-data-using-aes-techniques.

But this says that i have to use the php code level.

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide more information on the security architecture.
E.g. do you use HTTPS connections that makes sure that the data is not sent raw? At first sight your requirement looks a bit unusual.

Comment: @Elyasin:yes we are using Https.My client requires this feature and to me this is unusual.

Comment: That's strange. Even for confidential health data, [this should be sufficient](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2015/01/28/design-and-implementation-of-csvexcel-upload-for-saas/#comment-22723).

Comment: What is your threat model? What/who are you protecting data from by encrypting it in the database?

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Client doesn't say that clearly.May be from Developers or System Maintainers

Comment: The only way to do that is end2end encryption where the user's private key is only known by him.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan can you help me on that more?.specific totorial may be

Answer (score 0):

> We are using Laravel 5. Can we encrypt data in mysql server without using any PHP functions?

It's doable, but unwise. You're better off encrypting in PHP and that way the dataabse only ever sees encrypted values.

Aside: Do you expect it to be compatible with Laravel's encryption library? That balloons the complexity of such an undertaking.